# What is lambda in scheme

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I am VERY new to scheme. Very basic question for everyone. What is lambda in function calls I see everywhere online? What does it do? What do I lose by not using it?

Comment: Something clearer than this? http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Lambda-Expressions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda` is a special form in the family of Lisp programming langauges (and in other languages with some degree of support for functional programming), it's an anonymous function that creates a closure around the context in which it was defined.

Lambdas are used everywhere in Lisp, either explicitly or implicitly (behind macro transformations, implicitly in other special forms, etc.) What would you lose by not using it? *Everything*. For starters, the ability to define procedures!

To see some examples of what I mean, this procedure definition:

```
(define (f x)
  x)
```

... Is just syntactic sugar for this, a *named* procedure that simply associates a name to the anonymous `lambda`:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    x))
```

Similarly, the `let` form that binds values to variables:

```
(let ((x 9))
  (+ x 1))
```

... Is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
((lambda (x)
   (+ x 1))
 9)
```

Of course, lambdas can be used as a quick way to define anonymous functions:

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x))
     '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Truth be told, it's almost impossible *not* to use lambdas for writing any non-trivial program in Lisp.

Comment: @SpiffyDeveloper You're using a lambda there, implicitly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my old comment when I realized what you ment. This is very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Lambda is a functional literal.  An analogy may help:

Let's say I want to display the number 10.  I can do it two ways.  First, I can put it in a variable and then display the variable, like so:

```
(define x 10)
(display x)
```

Alternatively, I can just display the number directly -- a numeric literal -- like so:

```
(display 10)
```

Well a lambda is the same.  For instance, if I want to display the results of applying a function that adds two numbers, I can put that function in a variable and display the result like so:

```
(define f (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
(display (f 10 20))
```

Or I can just use a function literal -- lambda -- like so:

```
(display ((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 10 20))
```

As an aside, Scheme gives you a short-hand for defining functions, which can hide the true nature of lambda.  I could also define f with:

```
(define (f x y) (+ x y))
```

But I wanted to make the correspondence clear.

Lambdas are useful for the same reason numeric literals are useful.  In Scheme, you can have functions that take other functions as arguments.  Well sometimes you want to use one of those with a "one-off" function and thus don't want to bother giving it a name.  For instance, let's look at map, which applies a function to a list:

```
(map f my-list)
```

Produces a new list whose result is f applied to each element.  So what if I want to increment each element of a list?  I could do:

```
(define inc (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
(display (map inc '(1 2 3)))
```

But if we pretend this inc is a one-off thing, then I might not want to bother defining the name, hence I could do:

```
(display (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3)))
```

Another place lambda is useful is if you want to create something like a control structure, but don't want to use macros.  Well, I can wrap what I want to do with lambda, and since it inherits the context it's in, it works perfectly well.  For instance, let's pretend I need to write my own version of "for-each".  Here's the outline:

```
(define for-each (lambda (collection body) 
     ...))
```

Where body is a lambda representing the body of the "control-structure".

Then I'd use it like so:

```
(for-each collection (lambda (element)
    ...))
```

You can also use lambdas to dynamically build functions with other arguments; a big place this pays off is if you want to do some manual currying.  I won't get into the details because I may have went too far already, but I hope you can see that lambda gives you a lot of power without introducing much complexity.  This also should answer your question about what you lose by not using it.

Function literals (aka anonymous functions) are a big deal in functional programming, and they're also growing in imperative languages.  Mastering this feature can make your life a lot easier and help you in learning some of the other languages out there.